# Find the maximum value of a matrix subset in MATLAB while preserving the indices of the full matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, max, subset

Currently, I'm able to find the max value of a matrix `C` and its index with the following code:

```
[max_C, imax] = max(C(:));
[ypeak, xpeak] = ind2sub(size(C),imax(1));
```

Let's call a subset of the matrix `C_sub`

I want to find the max value of `C_sub`, but I also want to know the index of that max value in `C`.

Seems like it should be an easy problem, but it has me stumped.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that `C_sub` was created by

```
C_sub = C(rows,cols);
```

where `rows` and `cols` are vectors of indices.  Save those `rows` and `cols` vectors somewhere you can reuse them, if you haven't already.

```
[max_C_sub, ind_C_sub] = max(C_sub(:));
[ypeak_sub, xpeak_sub] = ind2sub(size(C_sub), ind_C_sub);
xpeak = cols(xpeak_sub);
ypeak = rows(ypeak_sub);
```

Or if `rows` and/or `cols` was a vector of logicals instead of a vector of indices, you can convert them using [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/find.html), and then proceed as above.

```
rows_ind = find(rows_logical);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the indices of the maximum in `C_sub`, and you know the position of `C_sub` within `C`, you can simply add them up (and subtract 1 for Matlab indexing) to get the indices of the maximum relative to `C`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once, so I wrote a little utility to do this. Find [Min2 and Max2](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22995-min2-max2) on the file exchange. These tools allow you to specify a subset of the rows and/or the columns of the given matrix to search over.

Do the same thing for yourself. Every time you need a tool in MATLAB, write it. Before long you will have built up a nice toolbox of tools tailored to your own special needs. Of course, look on the file exchange first, as there is a good chance that what you need has already been written and posted there.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
mask = nan(size(C));
mask(C_sub_indices) = 1;
[max_C, imax] = max(C .* mask);
```

In that code, `C_sub_indices` is the index expression applied to `C` that produced `C_sub`.  This code may not work if `C_sub` is not a submatrix of `C` (e.g., if it rearranges the rows or columns).

Comment: Umm, divide-by-zero gives infinity?

Comment: I just fixed it; the goal is to get NaN, not infinity.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this script:

```
A=magic(5)
[x,y]=find(A==max(max(A))) %index maximum of the matrix A 
A_max=A(x,y)
[x1,y1]=find(A==min(max(A))) %index minimum of the matrix A 
A_min=A(x1,y1)
```